# Rails view syntax error when embedding JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I'm getting a syntax error with the following code when embedding it into a Rails view:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var foo = "<%= @somevar %>";
</script>
```

What's the correct way of handling this?

Answer (score 1):

If its a javascript syntax error, then you may need to force rails not to sanitize the output of your @somevar, by either using raw(), or escape_javascript() or both